# Python Seaborn: how to plot all columns and use index as hue?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| index | 9 | 1 | 8 | 3 | 7 | 6 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 32941 | 3545 | 2829 | 2423 | 1945 | 1834 | 1213 | 1205 | 1096 | 969 |
| 1 | 24352 | 2738 | 2666 | 2432 | 1388 | 7937 | 682 | 3539 | 2705 | 1561 |
| 2 | 2137 | 1271 | 2401 | 540 | 3906 | 1446 | 3432 | 24855 | 1885 | 8127 |

I want to use barplot to plot these values, and use the index as hue. How can I do that? It can be matplotlib or seaborn or any tool, but I prefer the first two.

Comment: I tried on my own data set just rename some value. Hope it help [Notebook](https://imgur.com/a/mvdp3NV)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='index')
sns.barplot(x = 'variable', y = 'value' , data = df, hue = 'index' )
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

NOTE: If you wanna add the values on the top of each bar use:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,8))

ax = sns.barplot(x = 'variable', y = 'value' , data = df, hue = 'index' )

for p in ax.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., height + 300, int(height) , ha="center", fontsize= 'small')
```

OUTPUT:

[image]